# Why am I getting an error with this SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This Is the question that I'm supposed to be answering:

2. Write a script that uses two variables to store (1) the count of all of the products in the Products table and (2) the average list price for those products. If the product count is greater than or equal to 7, the script should print a message that displays the values of both variables. Otherwise, the script should print a message that says, “The number of products is less than 7”.

And here is my SQL statement:

```
USE MyGuitarShop;

DECLARE @AllProduct2 INT;
DECLARE @AvgAllListPrice MONEY;
SET @AllProduct2 = (SELECT COUNT(ProductID) FROM Products);
SET @AvgAllListPrice = (SELECT AVG (ListPrice) FROM Products);
IF @AllProduct2 > 7
    BEIGN
        PRINT 'The number of products is greater than or equal to 7';
        PRINT 'The average list price for the products is $' + CONVERT (varchar,@AvgAllListPrice,1);
    END;
ELSE 
    PRINT 'The number of products is less than 7';
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

EDIT

Sorry for not adding the error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'BEIGN'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

I ended up fixing it by reworking my code:

```
    USE MyGuitarShop;

    DECLARE @AllProduct2 INT;
    DECLARE @AvgListPrice MONEY;
    SELECT @AllProduct2 = COUNT(ProductID),
    @AvgListPrice = AVG (ListPrice)
    FROM Products
    IF @AllProduct2 > 7
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'The number of products is greater than or equal to 7';
            PRINT 'The average list price is $' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, @AvgListPrice,1) + '.';
        END;
    ELSE
        PRINT 'The number of products is less than 7';
```

Sorry again and thanks to those who helped me out!!!!!

Comment: Incorrecting spelling BEIGN

Comment: When asking a question regarding why code *isn't* working, it's very helpful if you include the error message, as well as the behavior you're getting and the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Since when you can `PRINT` in a query, or anywhere in mysql in general?

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  This syntax really looks like SQL Server.

Comment: You can print in a query, I do it all the time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misspelling in `BEGIN`

Comment: Not sure why the negative vote when this is the cause of the issue

Comment: Some people vote down answers to questions where OP made typographical error instead of just closing the question.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using  `SELECT ... INTO ...` syntax.  This also allows you to set both variables with a single query.

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductID), AVG(ListPrice) INTO @AllProduct2, @AvgAllListPrice FROM PRODUCTS
```

Or alternative assignment syntax

```
SELECT @AllProduct2 := COUNT(ProductID), @AvgAllListPrice := AVG(ListPrice) FROM PRODUCTS
```

Right now you are trying to assign a result set to your variable, not the values contained within that result set.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted.  Would be interested in comments from downvoters.

Comment: Thanks this helped me realize what I was doing wrong.

Comment: It should be required to make a comment if you downvote